# in C#, Is it possible to specifies category argument like setlocale() in C++?

Tags: c#, internationalization, culture

I have this C++ code

```
static const int category[] = {LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LC_MONETARY,                       LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME};
int op;
...
/* op = 0;  => The entire locale. */
op = 3; /* => Affects monetary formatting information */
char *setl = setlocale(category[op], "fr-FR");
```

I find

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
// OR
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

which I think must be the equivalent of

> setlocale( LC_ALL, "fr-FR" );

But in C#, how can I specifies the category argument for change locale information of a program?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and it's members as [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and after that instance change any single piece of that information accordingly.

Quoting an example in MSDN link:

```
// Clones myCI and modifies the DTFI and NFI instances associated with the clone.
CultureInfo myCIclone = (CultureInfo) myCI.Clone();
myCIclone.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "a.m.";
myCIclone.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
```

and after

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCIclone;
```

Comment: OK.  But what are properties of CultureInfo corresponding to each category of setlocale ()?

Comment: @PapyRef: you may look, apart of already presented DateTimeFormat, on [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is always a type of NumberFormat property inside CultureInfo class.